# Multidimensional array setAttrib on lane

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and everything works fine.
But I want to have the items in the right lane.
I get error messages when I use set attribute.

```
foreach ($lane_item_stores as $key=>$value) {
  foreach ($value as $items){
    echo '<td>' . $items->getAttrib('title') . '</td>' ;
  }
}
```

The output is ok, but they are not in the right lane.
Somebody told me I have to use set Attribute with id lane, but when I do that I get also error messages

Comment: Sorry i will do it it is PHP7

Comment: foreach ($lane_item_stores as $key=>$value){
  foreach ($value as $items){
   $sw = new SwFeature();
   $sw->setAttrib('id_lane', $val);
   $sw->getAll();
   echo '<tr>'.'<td>' . $sw->getAttrib('title') . '</td>'.'</tr>' ;

  }
}
That is still not working!

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: I get nothing.
The lanes are set with $val in a other foreach that works fine.
When I use this :
foreach ($lane_item_stores as $key=>$value){
 $sw = new SwFeature();
 $sw->setAttrib('id_lane', $val);
  foreach ($value as $items){
   $sw->get();
   echo '<tr>'.'<td>' . $sw->getAttrib('title') . '</td>'.'</tr>' ;
  }
}
The only thing what I get is the last item and not in the right lane what is set with $val

Comment: **FYI** php arrays does not have `getAttrib`. Also from naming `$items` I assume it's array, and you can't use it as object

Comment: This works
foreach ($lane_item_stores as $key=>$value){

 foreach ($value as $items){
  $sw = new SwFeature();
  $sw->setAttrib('id_lane', $lane_ids);
  $sw->getAll();
  echo '<tr><td>'. $items->getAttrib('title') . '</td></tr>';



  }
}
But I want it on a table all the items are now under each other